# Draw an arc with a SweepGradient in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

How can I draw an arc using a Shader such as SweepGradient?

The examples I have all take a Paint object:

```
Paint lightRed = new Paint();
lightRed.setAntiAlias(true);
lightRed.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
lightRed.setStrokeWidth(12);
lightRed.setColor(0xFFCC0000);
...
canvas.drawArc(rectf, -90, 360, false, lightRed);
```

Don't think it makes a difference, but I'm using it to draw to a homescreen widget

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
Shader gradient = new SweepGradient (0,getMeasuredHeight()/2, Color.RED, Color.WHITE);
lighted.setShader(gradient);
canvas.drawArc(rectf, -90, 360, false, lightRed);
```

You can modify the position and color values.