# Android Canvas Draw background with different color with transition between colors

Tags: android, canvas, paint

Need a direction- how to mix the colors on the canvas for the arc . Thanks in advance

### Current Output

[image: Current Output]

### Desired Output

[image]

Comment: see `android.graphics.SweepGradient`

Comment: Okay let me check.Thanks

Comment: More info. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11140377/5241603

Comment: more info. see here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037108/android-how-to-draw-an-arc-based-gradient

Comment: Is there any logic to put value to cx , cy in SweepGradient(float cx, float cy, int color0, int color1) . Because I am not getting the desired result .